# White space between two horizontal images

Tags: html, css

can anyone help me on how to remove the huge white space between the two images? Both images are in their respective divs with layer effects when hovered. I have tried changing display to inline-block and setting font-size to 0 but nothing works. I also want the two images to be at the center when adjusted. I may have incorrectly apply the mentioned efforts to different classes or divs throughout the process but I am not sure where I did wrong.

Attached are the html and css along with a screenshot of how it looks like on local server. I hope the attachments are useful. Thank you.

[image]

```css
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.campus-col{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.campus-col img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}
.layer{
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover{
    background: rgba(226,0,0,0.7);
}
.layer h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover h3{
    bottom: 49%;
    opacity: 1;
```

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="#">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>TEXT</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="#">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>MESSENGER</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like? For example, how much space between the images? And do you want them to be at the 32% width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make row flex container, then align content to center, with gap you can make space between images:

```css
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
.campus-col{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.campus-col img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}
.layer{
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover{
    background: rgba(226,0,0,0.7);
}
.layer h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover h3{
    bottom: 49%;
    opacity: 1;
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>TEXT</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>MESSENGER</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

If so you just need to use `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-start`

```css
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.campus-col{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.campus-col img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}
.layer{
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.layer:hover{
    background: rgba(226,0,0,0.7);
}
.layer h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}
.layer:hover h3{
    bottom: 49%;
    opacity: 1;
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>TEXT</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="campus-col">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <div class="layer">
                <a href="#"><h3>MESSENGER</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I've tried this method but it doesn't work. For some reason all other elements from the page were also adjusted according to the new property too despite not being in the same class or div. I have received the specific solution to my problem from other user.

Comment: good to hear you've solved your problem. 
I'll leave my answer for others to read

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap class for width .campus-col or use custom width

Answer (score 1):

You can use (`justify-content: center`) to *center* the `children` in the `flex` displayed `parent`, in short: center the `.img` in `.row`.

Then you can add `margin` for spaces between them (the method used in the code below).

Or you can use (`justtify-content: space-between`) and set the `width` of the *parent* (`.row`), then each `.img` will be at the edge or it's direction (left or right)

Check this for more detalis: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**The Code:**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.img {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img img1"></div>
  <div class="img img2"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution based on your code:**

Edited:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.campus-col{
    height: 200px; /* delete later, added to see the changes */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* delete later, added to see the changes */
    margin: 0 10px; /* add/remove spaces (left right of each one) */
}
```

**The Code:**

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.campus-col{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.campus-col img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}

.layer{
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.layer:hover{
    background: rgba(226,0,0,0.7);
}

.layer h3{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 26px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.layer:hover h3{
    bottom: 49%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="campus-col">
        <img src="#">
        <div class="layer">
            <a href="#"><h3>TEXT</h3></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="campus-col">
        <img src="#">
        <div class="layer">
            <a href="#"><h3>MESSENGER</h3></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you sir, I applied this to my code but there's no noticeable changes to the page. Appreciate the help but I have solved the problem.